# Processing JSON object via Webservice in PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, acl, pljson

I am developing a test Oracle Procedure to receive a JSON object from a locally XAMPP hosted web-service. Followed below steps.

(01) **Created the ACL**

```
set define off;
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => 'www.xml',
                                    description => 'TEST JSON',
                                    principal   => 'TEST_USER',
                                    is_grant    => true,
                                    privilege   => 'connect',
                                    start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                                    end_date     => NULL);

SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl       => 'www.xml',
                                       principal => 'TEST_USER',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve');

SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'www.xml',
                                    host        => 'localhost',
                                    lower_port  => 8081,
                                    upper_port  => NULL);
END;
```

(02) **Following is the test proc**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE JSON11 IS
  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);
  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_list system.json_list;
  acl            VARCHAR2(100);
  url            VARCHAR2(1000) := 
  'http://localhost:8081/PhpProjectFirst/displayValuesSent.php?
  name=name11&email=name11@gmail.com&gender=male&course=OCA2&class=2008&s
  ubject=PL/SQL';

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('start');
    l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST','HTTP/1.1');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('aa');
    --utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
    utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    --utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', 
    length(content));    
    --utl_http.write_text(l_http_request, content);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('bb');
    l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('cc');

    -- process the response from the HTTP call
    begin
        loop
            utl_http.read_line(l_http_response, l_response_text);
            dbms_output.put_line(l_response_text);
        end loop;
        utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);

    end;   
exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body then
        utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
    when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error >> '||sqlerrm);
END JSON11;
```

(03) **Called the proc**

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
BEGIN
  JSON11();
END;
```

**But end with below error.**

```
Error >> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-29270: too many open HTTP requests
```

DB is Oracle XE and using Oracle SQL Developer.
Webservice is very simple and run via XAMPP and returns a simple JSON object.

Any tips could be shared?

Regards,
LM

Comment: Why is this tagged with `pljson`?

Comment: I have used PL/JSON projects' JSON objects to refer the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a maximum of 5 HTTP requests per session. 
With each run of the procedure you are creating one new connection but you do not always close it.
You are closing your connections only in `when utl_http.end_of_body then`, but you should also close it in `when others then`.

Comment: Excellent. It has worked!Thank you very much for the advice.